# Is there a way for 3rd party API to capture user screen time information (raw data) with new IOS API changes in IOS 15 and 16?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

. Are there any other API which providing  Apple provided API
. We are used this Documentation : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screentime
. Is there any other IOS-provided API that I may have been provided which could assist in capturing user screen time information after their user consent?

1. I have used family control framework.
2. I am expecting to get device activity raw data.

Comment: No. You definitely shouldn't expect to get raw data. That would be a significant privacy impact. If you have a specialized use case, you should open a FB to Apple to discuss it. They do create new APIs to handle specific use case, but they generally never give raw data.